# Передача параметра из shell скрипта в python скрипт и запуск этого скрипта

Tags: python, shell, linux

Как передать из shell скрипта параметры в python скрипт и запустить этот  скрипт?

Comment: запустить из shell python скрипт с параметрами ?

/path/to/script parameter1 parameter2

Comment: не из shell, а из shell скрипта.

Comment: что из shell что из shell скрипта - разницы нет.

Answer (score 2):

например, так:

```
python путь-к-python-скрипту параметр1 параметр2 ...
```

сохраняете в файл, например, `shell-скрипт`, и вызываете:

```
$ sh shell-скрипт
```